# Doctrine ORM: Validate schema with manually added fk with option on update cascade

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, onupdate

I have two related PostgreSQL tables: persons(.., person_department_id,..) and departments(department_id, ..) with foreign keys properties "ON UPDATE CASCADE". I can't change this behavior, because data comes from external database by a script, i. e. departments.department_id can be changed without Symfony 3 application, but I must to implement a partial editing of records in those tables with Symfony 3 app.

My Q: Because "onUpdate" property has been removed from Doctrine ORM, how I can to validate the database schema? Or, maybe I can't use ORM and must to use only DBAL in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [Symfony's validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) for this purpose.

You can set validation rules for any entity property or for the entire class.

Depending on your needs it's possible to create custom validators for more complexes validation rules.

Comment: Thanx a lot, but it is a bit different for my needs: when I try to update schema with doctrine command, doctrine breaks the foreign key's "on update cascade".